# Ionic JSON локально

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, phonegap, ionic

Как с помощью Angular/Ionic на телефоне локально создавать файл JSON, читать его, редактировать?
Не могу найти нигде вменяемых примеров кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать "window.localStorage" для хранение json.

```
var json = '{ "name": "Eugene" }';
window.localStorage['person'] = json;

console.log( window.localStorage['person'] );
// '{ "name": "Eugene" }'
```

Comment: и это не будет уничтожаться после того как пользователь выйдет из системы? какие условия уничтожения информации в windows.localStorage?

Comment: информация будет хранится до того времени пока пользователь не почистит кэш.

Comment: и это не будет уничтожаться после того как пользователь выйдет из системы.